# Poor LLVM JIT performance

Tags: performance, llvm, jit

I have a legacy C++ application that constructs a tree of C++ objects.  I want to use LLVM to call class constructors to create said tree.  The generated LLVM code is fairly straight-forward and looks like repeated sequences of:

```
; ...
%11 = getelementptr [11 x i8*]* %Value_array1, i64 0, i64 1
%12 = call i8* @T_string_M_new_A_2Pv(i8* %heap, i8* getelementptr inbounds ([10 x i8]* @0, i64 0, i64 0))
%13 = call i8* @T_QueryLoc_M_new_A_2Pv4i(i8* %heap, i8* %12, i32 1, i32 1, i32 4, i32 5)
%14 = call i8* @T_GlobalEnvironment_M_getItemFactory_A_Pv(i8* %heap)
%15 = call i8* @T_xs_integer_M_new_A_Pvl(i8* %heap, i64 2)
%16 = call i8* @T_ItemFactory_M_createInteger_A_3Pv(i8* %heap, i8* %14, i8* %15)
%17 = call i8* @T_SingletonIterator_M_new_A_4Pv(i8* %heap, i8* %2, i8* %13, i8* %16)
store i8* %17, i8** %11, align 8
; ...
```

Where each `T_` function is a C "thunk" that calls some C++ constructor, e.g.:

```
void* T_string_M_new_A_2Pv( void *v_value ) {
  string *const value = static_cast<string*>( v_value );
  return new string( value );
}
```

The thunks are necessary, of course, because LLVM knows nothing about C++.  The `T_` functions are added to the `ExecutionEngine` in use via `ExecutionEngine::addGlobalMapping()`.

When this code is JIT'd, the performance of the JIT'ing itself is very poor.  I've generated a [call-graph](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/46791180/callgraph.pdf) using `kcachegrind`.  I don't understand all the numbers (and this PDF seems not to include commas where it should), but if you look at the left fork, the bottom two ovals, `Schedule...` is called 16K times and `setHeightToAtLeas...` is called 37K times. On the right fork, `RAGreed...` is called 35K times.

Those are far too many calls to *anything* for what's mostly a simple sequence of `call` LLVM instructions. Something seems horribly wrong.

Any ideas on how to improve the performance of the JIT'ing?

Comment: This would be a good question to take to the llvmdev mailing list

Comment: I already asked on the LLVM mailing list. Only 1 guy replied initially, but, after continued discussion, stopped replying.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, compiling with -o3? Also, it might be worth taking a look at the generated code. The functions you mentioned - scheduling and register allocation (RAGreed) - are part of the codegen phase, long after the LLVM IR has already been lowered and no longer looks like the original.

Comment: I changed it to use `CodeGenOpt::None` and the performance improved by an order of magnitude.  However, I'd still like to improve it by yet another order of magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

Another order of magnitude is unlikely to happen without a huge change in how the JIT works or looking at the particular calls you're trying to JIT. You could enable -fast-isel-verbose on llc -O0 (e.g. llc -O0 -fast-isel-verbose mymodule.[ll,bc]) and get it to tell you if it's falling back to the selection dag for instruction generation. You may want to profile again and see what the current hot spots are.